# Why Array.prototype is not instance of Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote my own `isArray` function:

```
Array.isArray = function(value) {
  if (value instanceof Array) {
    console.log(true);
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log(false);
    return false;
  }
};

var isArray = Array.isArray;

isArray('String'); // false
isArray(202929); // false
isArray(true); // false
isArray(false); // false
isArray({}); // false
isArray(Array.prototype); // false, but must be true
isArray([]); // true
```

Why `Array.prototype` is not instance of `Array` since `Array.prototype` returns `[]`?

```
> Array.prototype
[]
> Array.prototype instanceof Array
false
```

Comment: Array.prototype instanceof Object = true

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to implement `isArray`:

```
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Comment: The question is why is `Array.prototype` not an `instanceof Array`

Comment: thanks for your answer @Amir, but i really want understand why Array.prototype is not an instanceof Array, like haim said..